# How change date type in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to keep column default value as current date in mysql.what should be its type.i tryied date and timestamp but not allowed.can anybody say me what should be appropriate data type?

Morely i want to keep default value as current date.how it can be done.At begining default value was set

Comment: Um, perhaps see the manual for your version of MySQL for DATE and TIME data types. Note that the most recent version of MySQL offers more options in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN realdate DATE;
UPDATE MyTable SET realdate = STR_TO_DATE(textdate, '%d/%m/%y');
```

Comment: actually i want to keep default value as current date.how it can be done

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname  TIMESTAMP;
```

More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

**Updated**

Simply:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE columnnane TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

[More details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: actually i want to keep default value as current date.how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE  `tablename` CHANGE  `fieldname`  `fieldname` datatype( 11) NOT NULL